# Where in the code and what is lazy loaded, the transaction or session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

This nhibernate setup suggests that it is better because I believe it doesn't start a transaction when the session is opened unless it is explicilty called i.e. lazy loaded.

I can't seem to grasp where in the code this lazy loading is taking place: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx

Can someone explain on this approach is better then opening a new transaction per web request?

Answer (score 2):

1. the writer doesn't suggest that it's better because it doesn't start a transaction (it actually does- see the `BeginSession` function), but because it doesn't *always* start a *session*.
2. the 'lazy' refers to the intialization of the session.
   Meaning- the session is only started when it's required.
   (You're confusing it with lazy loading which has to do with loading values from the database, and is not relevant here).

The 'lazy' part is, as the writer explains, that the `OpenSession` function isn't called until it's needed (i.e someone is trying to use the Session object).